# No Markers Showing After Integrating Overlapping Marker Spiderfier with Google Map v3

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps, pug, markerspiderfier

Currently trying to integrate the Overlapping Marker Spiderfier add-on into a Google Map setup. I am passing the location data to a Jade Template from MongoDB.

Before utilising the add-on, I used a for loop to create markers from an array of co-cordinates. These were displayed as expected.

However, when I integrated the Spiderfier code, the markers are no longer added to the map. The map is still displayed, but the JavaScript console is returning a `Uncaught Reference Error - OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is not defined` message. Does this mean the call to the add-on is incorrect? I am fully ready to accept that I have missed something obvious but have so far tried the following to no avail:

- Comparing my code to add-on examples available
- Comparing my code to other SO answers

Here is the code concerning the Google Map:

```
script(src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASXfB-y1pwF_S-qToDhYL7doiHrUFOx0Q&sensor=false")
script(src"http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js")

script.
    var locationArray = [];
each tweetlocations, i in locationlist
    script.
        var latitude = "#{tweetlocations.latitude}";
        var longitude = "#{tweetlocations.longitude}";

        var markerlocation = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        locationArray.push(markerlocation);

script.
    function initialize()
    {

        var mapProp = {
            center:markerlocation,
            zoom:1,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,{markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true});

        var usualColor = 'eebb22';
        var spiderfiedColor = 'ffee22';
        var iconWithColor = function(color) {
            return 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|+|' + color + '|000000|ffff00';
        }
        var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
            new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
        );

        oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
            iw.open(map, marker);
        });

        oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
            for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++) {
                markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(spiderfiedColor));
                markers[i].setShadow(null);
            } 
            iw.close();
        });

        oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function(markers) {
            for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++) {
                markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(usualColor));
                markers[i].setShadow(shadow);
            }
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var coord;
        for (coord in locationArray) {
            bounds.extend(coord);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locationArray[coord],
                map: map,
                icon: iconWithColor(usualColor),
                shadow: shadow
            });
            oms.addMarker(marker);
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What does the javascript console tell you (regarding javascript errors)?

Comment: Didn't know about that handy tool- new to JavaScript (as I'm sure was obvious) so thanks! Its saying that there is an 'Uncaught Reference Error: OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is not defined'. Guessing this means my calling of the add-on script is incorrect.

Comment: You are probably getting an error that says [it](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js) isn't executable or something like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you made a small typo inside the second script() function, missing the `=` sign between src and url. Consequently the external Spiderfier script wasn't getting loaded, which explains `OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is not defined`.

So change

```
script(src"http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js")
```

so it includes a `=`

```
script(src="http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js")
```